# When using the Colormap command a new window opens

Tags: matlab, colors, matlab-figure

When I change the colormap in the MatLab environment to grayscale with the line

```
colormap gray(256);
```

a new blank window opens. Semicolon in the end of the line makes no differens.
How can I avoid that?

Comment: syntax-wise, the line should be: `colormap(gray(256))` (i.e: use function form instead of the command form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colormap` applies to a figure.  If you don't specify a figure, then it uses the current figure by default.  If there is no current figure, then one gets created (this is the same behaviour that you get for lots of commands, e.g. `xlim`).

Comment: Okay. So my only option will be to make a `close(figure(1))` afterwards I guess?

Comment: @Steeven: But this won't achieve anything.  What are you trying to apply the colormap to?

Comment: I'm making a function that converts an image to grayscale. Then I would like to specify the colormap in the function, so the user doesn't have to do it manually. But as I see it now, colormap will not be a saved setting, and if the window that opens is closed, it is forgotten again. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks for a quick an good answer that moved my understanding of MatLab another step.